# Changing name of the video while downloading via youtube-dl

Tags: linux, video, youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to download a complete playlist in youtube, while downloading i want to enter serial number while downloading in front of the title of the video,

For example if a playlist has a videos:

```
A.mp4
E.mp4
K.mp4
C.mp4
B.mp4
```

I want it to be

```
1. A.mp4
2. E.mp4
3. K.mp4
4. C.mp4
5. B.mp4.
```

I tried commands like:

```
i=0;youtube-dl -cti https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={(Any Playlist)} -o "{{$i++}%(title)s.%(ext)s}"
```

but its giving me this error:

> youtube-dl: error: using output template conflicts with using title, video ID or auto number

Also, Downloading the whole playlist and then renaming one by one is also not i am searching.

Is there any command which downloads the playlist and renames each video side by side according to my wish?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sometimes I had headache to rename and sort the files based on the order.

So to add auto-numbering, use `-A` like,

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILe6_eGvDN3GyiodoV3qNSC -A
```

Or to keep playlist index,

```
youtube-dl -o '%(playlist_index)s. %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILe6_eGvDN3GyiodoV3qNSC
```

This will add nice numbering to the downloaded files.

And if you are downloading files which is not in playlist, you can add numbers manually to the file,

```
youtube-dl -o "1-%(uploader)s%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://youtu.be/862r3XS2YB0
```

Here I have manually added `1-` to the filename while downloading.

Comment: Just saying, -A option is deprecated, now it is recommended to use -o.

Comment: What if you already downloaded a terabyte long playlist and now what to rename the file accordingly? ;)  youtube-dl can download playlist metadata, but how to get this metadata in a form that can be used from a script to match already downloaded files and rename them?

Answer (score 9):

Use `youtube-dl -o '%(playlist_index)s. %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=...`.

Comment: Sir, thank you it worked but you added playlist index, what if I have to add my own number in front instead the playlist index, what shall I do?

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I found is:

```
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" <playlist_link>
```

For example:

```
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf8i4fc0zJBzLhOe6FwHpGhBDgqwInJWZ
```

Comment: What to do if I already have downloaded the video and would like to rename it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
'outtmpl': 'temp/' + str(i) +'.%(ext)s'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the youtube link in the quotes ""

example

```
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNObiptSMSI&list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been using lately.

```
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" -f best "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID"
```